# Why doesn't .join() work with function arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, join

Why does this work (returns "one, two, three"):

```
var words = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$("#main").append('<p>' + words.join(", ") + '</p>');
```

and this work (returns "the list: 111"):

```
var displayIt = function() {
    return 'the list: ' + arguments[0];
}   
$("#main").append('<p>' + displayIt('111', '222', '333') + '</p>');
```

but not this (returns blank):

```
var displayIt = function() {
    return 'the list: ' + arguments.join(",");
}   
$("#main").append('<p>' + displayIt('111', '222', '333') + '</p>');
```

**What do I have to do to my "arguments" variable to be to use .join() on it?**

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424710/why-is-my-join-on-a-javascript-array-failing

Comment: I've amended my answer to take into account your updated question -- specifically, the "what do I have to do to make this work?" part.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `arguments` object is not an array, although it looks like it. It has no `join` method:

```
>>> var d = function() { return '[' + arguments.join(",") + ']'; }
>>> d("a", "b", "c")
TypeError: arguments.join is not a function
```

To convert `arguments` to an array, you can do:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Now `join` will work:

```
>>> var d = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return '[' + args.join(",") + ']';
}
>>> d("a", "b", "c");
"[a,b,c]"
```

Alternatively, you can use jQuery's **[`makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)**, which will try to turn "almost-arrays" like `arguments` into arrays:

```
var args = $.makeArray(arguments);
```

Here's what the **[Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arguments)** (my favorite resource for this sort of thing) has to say about it:

> The `arguments` object is not an array.
>   It is similar to an array, but does
>   not have any array properties except
>   `length`. For example, it does not have
>   the pop method. ...
>
> The `arguments` object is available only
>   within a function body. Attempting to
>   access the arguments object outside a
>   function declaration results in an
>   error.

Comment: or `Array.join(arguments, ",")` (like `Array.forEach(arguments, func);`)

Comment: what happens when one of your arguments is an object?

Comment: @Anonymous 
TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'join'

Comment: `Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ', ')`

Answer (score 23):

If you are not interested on other `Array.prototype` methods, and you want simply to use `join`, you can invoke it directly, without converting it to an array:

```
var displayIt = function() {
    return 'the list: ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ',');
};
```

Also you might find useful to know that the comma is the default separator, if you don't define a separator, by [spec](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4.4.5) the comma will be used.

Comment: +1 This is the fastest and safest answer *IF* all you want is to call join instead of creating a new array. Calling slice just to join will allocate memory when join works on array-like objects as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this [jQuery .joinObj Extension/Plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/uUyrc/) I made.

As you'll see in that fiddle, you can use it as follows:

```
$.joinObj(args, ",");
```

or

```
$.(args).joinObj(",");
```

---

Plugin Code:

```
(function(c){c.joinObj||(c.extend({joinObj:function(a,d){var b="";if("string"===typeof d)for(x in a)switch(typeof a[x]){case "function":break;case "object":var e=c.joinObj(a[x],d);e!=__proto__&&(b+=""!=b?d+e:e);break;default:"selector"!=x&&"context"!=x&&"length"!=x&&"jquery"!=x&&(b+=""!=b?d+a[x]:a[x])}return b}}),c.fn.extend({joinObj:function(a){return"object"===typeof this&&"string"===typeof a?c.joinObj(this,a):c(this)}}))})(jQuery);
```

Comment: and ... why the -1? this is a working plug that does exactly as asked?

Comment: i hate it too, when people -1 my post without explanatian.. +1 for you.. T^T

Answer (score 2):

Just use the jQuery utility function [`makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)

`arguments` is not an Array, it is an object. But, since it so "array-like", you can call the jQuery utility function `makeArray` to make it work:

```
var displayIt = function() {
    return 'the list: ' + $.makeArray(arguments).join(",");
}   
$("#main").append('<p>' + displayIt('111', '222', '333') + '</p>');
```

Which will output:

```
<p>the list: 111,222,333</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can't join array arguments, because they aren't an array, [shown here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#From_arguments_to_an_array)

so you have to either first turn them into an array like this,

```
function f() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, f.length);
  return 'the list: ' + args.join(',');
}
```

or like this, a bit shorter

```
function displayIt() {
  return 'the list: ' + [].join.call(arguments, ',');
}
```

if you are using something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#default-rest-spread) or a compatible browser to use es6 features, you can also do this using rest arguments.

```
function displayIt(...args) {
  return 'the list: ' + args.join(',');
}

displayIt('111', '222', '333');
```

which would let you do even cooler stuff like

```
function displayIt(start, glue, ...args) {
  return start + args.join(glue);
}

displayIt('the start: ', '111', '222', '333', ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use typeof to see what's happening here:

```
>>> typeof(['one', 'two', 'three'])
"object"
>>> typeof(['one', 'two', 'three'].join)
"function"
>>> typeof(arguments)
"object"
>>> typeof(arguments.join)
"undefined"
```

Here you can see that typeof returns "object" in both cases but only one of the objects has a join function defined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a simple way to convert arguments into an array, but you can try this:

```
var toreturn = "the list:";
for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
{
   if(i != 0) { toreturn += ", "; }
   toreturn += arguments[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Array.from` and then `join()` with whatever token you'd like:

```
function joinArgs() {
  return Array.from(arguments).join(' ');
}

joinArgs('one', 'two', 'three'); // returns 'one two three'
```

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is not a jQuery object, just a regular JavaScript object.  Extend it before you try to call `.join()`.  I think you would write:

```
return 'the list:' + $(arguments)[0];
```

(I'm not too familiar with jQuery, only Prototype, so I hope this is not completely bogus.)

Edit:  It's wrong!  But in his response, Doug Neiner describes what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: This isn't quite right; `arguments` is not an array. Instead, it's an "array-like object".

Comment: A normal JS Array supports `join`.

Comment: if arguments is not an array, how come arguments[0] and arguments[1] give me the correct values passed to the function?

Comment: Edward: JavaScript objects can respond to [x] like they respond to .foo, it's not something that only array objects can do like in other languages.  I think.  I have been wrong before ;)

Comment: @Edward Tanguay: Here's a javascript object that is not an array but looks like one: `{1:'hello',2:'world',length:2}`. Notice that that object only has 3 properties: 1,2 and length. It does not have any methods attached to it. The `arguments` object is similar, the result of getElementsByTagName is another one.