# What does Object([]); do?

Tags: javascript, arrays

On a couple of polyfill examples in MDN for some Array prototype functions, there are the following two lines (e.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var list = Object(this);
var length = list.length >>> 0;
```

I presume the first example is autoboxing(?). But what is its purpose either way if `this` is always going to be an array anyway?

And line 2, how does this differ to:

```
var length = list.length || 0;
```

Thanks!

Comment: For the chevron operator, the best answer I've found so far is http://stackoverflow.com/a/1822769/4573999

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes it possible to call the function (using `call` or `apply`) in strict mode on something which isn't an array while following the specification.

If it's an instance of `Array`, or an array-like object, it changes nothing.

But here, as this line ensuring `list` is an object follows a check that `this` is neither `null` or `undefined`, and as other values wouldn't make the following accesses fail (apart very special cases that `Object(this)` wouldn't solve, like failing accessors), I'm not sure there's really a point. Maybe it was set before the check, or maybe it's here just in case of special native objects. Another possibility is that it (too?) strictly follows the [specification](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.find) step by step and wants to apply [toObject](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-toobject).

`list.length >>> 0` is better than `|| 0` in the fact it rounds to the nearest lower positive integer (in a 32 bits range). I'm not sure why `>>` wasn't used here, as it doesn't seem to be better to iterate until 4294967295 rather than to -1 (i.e. don't lose time).

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on the bit shifting vs OR?

Comment: `>>>` is better, because result is always *finite* *non-negative* *integer*, while `||` will happyly return string or object

Comment: When you say 'possible to call the function' which function do you mean?

Comment: @AmmarCSE, Denys means that the polyfilled function `find` can be called over an object which is not an `Array`. For example, read this popular answer for calling Array's function `join` over object `arguments` which is not an Array (and doesn't have all functions in prototype), although supports `length` and indexing http://stackoverflow.com/a/2091159/4573999

Comment: @DenysSequret I still find the reason for calling `Object()` function rather weak. I only see the difference in case `this` inside polyfill is `null` or `undefined`. For all other cases `Object(this)` doesn't change the nature of `this`, given the result will be only used for getting `length` property and indexing

Comment: @KirillSlatin You're totally right. I'm still thinking about it. The only reasons I see for now is that the `if` check wasn't present at first.