# Why would one use Array.prototype.forEach.call(array, cb) over array.forEach(cb)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I've just been looking over some photos from this year's ng-europe conference and noticed a slide I think might show some code from the upcoming Angular 2. See here:

[image: Example from ng-europe]

(Source: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/+ThierryLAU/albums/6073085583895256529/6073092865671487010?pid=6073092865671487010&oid=105910465983441810901)

## What I don't get is this:

Why is the author of this code using `Array.prototype.forEach.call(array, cb)` in preference to the shorter and (in my opinion) equivalent version `array.forEach(cb)`. The only reason I could imagine would be performance implications.

Does anybody know of another difference? Or am I maybe right with my performance guess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS - Why use Prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/js-why-use-prototype)

Comment: The main reason why `[].forEach.call(arr)` is used is to prevent array-like objects (`arguments` object, DOM node lists, etc.) throwing an error because `Array.prototype` is not in the prototype chain of those objects. Here's a very similar question, but asked from the other side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424710/why-is-my-join-on-a-javascript-array-failing

Comment: @Qantas. Thanks for the answer. But why did you leave it as a comment instead of an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are number of [Array-like objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like) which look like arrays, however are not. To name some:

- `arguments`
- `children` and `childNodes` collections
- NodeList collections returned by methods like `document.getElementsByClassName` and `document.querySelectorAll`
- jQuery collections
- and even strings.

Many array prototype methods are generic by purpose, which means that their internal implementation does not depend on context `this` to be an  instance of `Array` constructor. This allows to call those methods in the context of *other* objects which "look" like arrays. Namely, looking like an array means  that the object have numeric keys and length property.

Here is one useless example of how you can call `Array.prototype.join` on custom array-like object:

```
Array.prototype.join.call({0: 'one', 1: 'two', length: 2}, ' ');
```

Above will output string `"one two"`. However supplied object is clearly not an array.

Comment: but why does it still working if we pass as `this` the `window`? Is it Array-like object? For example: `Array.prototype.forEach.call( window, function( element, index, array ){ console.log(index, element, array) })`

Comment: @Sotiris Generally what you posted will not work on *any* page. I assume since it worked for you, you tested this script on the page with frames, am I right? One more time: to be an array-like object object must have length property and numeric keys: 0, 1, etc. If the document has frames then `window.length` show how many of them and window[0], window[1], etc. reference those frames/iframes in order they appear in document. So in this case `window` object indeed becomes array-like, because it allows access to some properties by numeric indexes and also has length  property.

Comment: thank you very much for the insight. Indeed it was the iframes of some plugins. Testing it on incognito returns undefined as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is being a bit defensive against `element.attributes` or `element.children` not being arrays.