# values.join is not a function in the file http.es5.js Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular 4 I have used a code snippet like;

```
let h = [{Content: 'application/json'}];

this.http.post(server, this.userDataObj, {headers: h}).....
```

So basically I wanted to add a header in my ajax call.

Now I am constantly getting an error

`ERROR TypeError: values.join is not a function`

I inspected the error location and I found at the file http.es5.js there is a code like;

```
 req.headers.forEach(function (name, values) {
      return xhr.setRequestHeader(name, values.join(',')); 
 });
```

Now I added a `console.log(req.headers)` just above the snippet, and I got ;

```
 [Object]
      0:Object
         Content: 'application/json'
```

Now as far as I know function inside forEach loop on array in JS takes second argument(which is values in http.es5.js) is the index of the element. And I tested via `console.log(values)` and I got result 0. So it is natural that **values.join is not a function**, and it will never be a function on an integer.

I tried ;

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content", 'application/json');

this.http.post(server, this.userDataObj, {headers: headers}).subscribe(.....
```

Which also giving me same error.

Tried this;

```
var h = new Headers();
h.append("kkk", 'aaa');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: h });

this.http.post(server, this.userDataObj, options).subscribe(.....
```

Still same error.

Is it a bug? Or am I doing any mistake?
Any idea will be very helpful for me.

PS: I am new to Angular4.

Comment: Headers aren't an array. They are ```RequestOptions``` object. This SO question should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133705/how-to-correctly-set-http-request-header-in-angular-2

Comment: I tried the your mentioned question's accepted answer, still same error. What I tried mention in the question now.Please check. I become clueless now. :(

Answer (score 6):

Angular 4.3:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: Create Headers as   ...   new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'content-language': 'en'  }) . ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Headers` from `angular/http` to add the headers to the request.

first use those imports

```
import { Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
```

then add the headers like this

```
var headers = new Headers();

headers.append("Content", 'application/json');

this.http.post(server, this.userDataObj, {headers: headers })
```

Comment: I tried it also,and tried just now.Still same error I am getting.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Api } from '../../providers/providers';


export class demo{

  response: any;     

  constructor(public api: Api){
     this.apiCall();
  }
  apiCall(){
     var headers = new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'token': 'token_demo'
      });

      this.response = this.api.post("services/user", {}, { headers: headers });
      this.response.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('data : ' + data);
      }, err => {
        console.error("error = ", err);
      }
  }
}
```

> this is working on ........